# Add data attribute with value from self

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table to which I'd like to add a attribute 'data-order' to every last child of every row. See the table below.

```
     <table id="table_id" class="display">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>255 500</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'd like to add the value of the last td to the attribute.

```
Before : <td>255 500</td>
After  : <td data-order"255 500">255 500</td>
```

I use $(this).text() to get the value from the td but it doesn't seem to work the way I thought. I get weird data with multiple table rows included. I use this Javascript code to add the attribute.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( '#table_id tbody tr td:last-child').attr( 'data-order', $(this).text());
    });
    </script>
```

What is wrong my code ? Thanks.

Comment: `$(this)` in your context is `$(document)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point `this` doesn't refer to your `$( '#table_id tbody tr td:last-child')`

I think you must declarate a var, something like this could help you

```
var $MyObject = $( '#table_id tbody tr td:last-child'); 
$MyObject.attr( 'data-order', $MyObject.text());
```

if you have multiple line in you table you could use `this` in a each loop.

Example case

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>Test</td>
         <td>255 500</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Test1</td>
          <td>255 5001</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Test2</td>
         <td>255 500</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table> 

$( '#table_id tbody tr td:last-child').each(function(){
  var $MyObject = $(this); // this here referer to the current object of the loop
  $MyObject.attr( 'data-order', $MyObject.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var lastTd = $( '#table_id tbody tr td:last-child');

lastTd.attr( 'data-order', lastTd.html());
```

Comment: what about if the TD have a `<span>` tag inside ?

Comment: @kevpoccs in his example he has only text so `.text()` `.html()` douse not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at below code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( '#table_id tbody tr').each(function(){
       $(this).find('td:last-child').attr( 'data-order', $(this).find('td:last-child').text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>255 500</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Test1</td>
            <td>2551 5001</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Test2</td>
            <td>2552 5002</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to **[.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** function as like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#table_id tr td:last-child').each(function(){
      var thisText = $(this).text();
    
      $(this).attr('data-order',thisText);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id" class="display">
         <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>255 500</td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>255 500</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#table_id tr td:last-child').each(function () {

            $(this).attr('data-order', $(this).text());
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `data()`

```
    $('#table_id tr td:last-child').each(function(){
         var text= $(this).text();    
         $(this).data('order',text);
    });
```